How to hide the sidebar on a specific nav_panel?
I have a shiny app that is using the bslib framework. I have two nav_panel "Page 1" and "Page 2" and a sidebar.
I do not want the sidebar to appear at all on page 2 only on page 1.
I have tried sidebar_toggle and conditionalPanel. My current app is more complex but here is a basic app to get started.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Sidebar updates",
  id = "nav",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    id = "sidebar",
    open = FALSE,
    "Sidebar"
  ),
  nav_panel("Page 1", "Sidebar closed. Go to Page 2 to open."),
  nav_panel("Page 2", "Sidebar open. Go to Page 1 to close.")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    sidebar_toggle(
      id = "sidebar",
      open = input$nav == "Page 2"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The goal is to get rid of the sidebar in the green box:

Overall my goal is to have something like this (obtained by a global sidebar)

Right now when I use layout_sidebar I lose the nice formatting


also, note that toggle_sidebar() has a bug in the bslib version 0.7.0, but is fixed in the development version. This does not solve your problem (for that, use layout_sidebar(), but I figured you would want to know. Bug fix is noted here: https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/blob/main/NEWS.md

We can use bslib::layout_sidebar():
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Sidebar updates",
  id = "nav",
  nav_panel("Page 1", "Sidebar closed. Go to Page 2 to open.",
            layout_sidebar(
              sidebar = sidebar("sidebar"),
              "Sidebar"
            )),
  nav_panel("Page 2", "Sidebar open. Go to Page 1 to close.")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    sidebar_toggle(
      id = "sidebar",
      open = input$nav == "Page 2"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Created on 2024-05-30 with reprex v2.0.2

Do you know how to get the sidebar on the left handside, for example when I use layout_sidebar from your example it looks like this (not automatically on the left and pushing everything to the right)
However when I just use the global sidebar it automatically goes to the left and pushes everything else to the right

@crazydatacatlady So you want the sidebar to stay open at all times? Then you can use open = "always" within sidebar().

An alternative would be to use tabsetPanel() instead of nav_panel():
  library(shiny)
    
  ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Sidebar updates",
  id = "nav",
  tabsetPanel(
   tabPanel(title = "Page 1",
            sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                       h4("My Sidebar")),
                          mainPanel())),
   tabPanel(title = "Page 2",
            sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel = "",
                          mainPanel()))
 )
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I hope this helps!

You can use layout_sidebar() in the panel where you want the sidebar:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

sb = sidebar(id='sidebar', open=T, "Sidebar Content")
np1 = nav_panel('Page 1', layout_sidebar("Sidebar only on this panel"), sidebar = sb)
np2 = nav_panel('Page 2', "No sidebar on this panel")

ui <- page_navbar(title = "Sidebar only on panel 1", id = "nav", np1, np2)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

